# Helper causing text to not show up

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-helper

The helper is supposed to look for hashtags and make them a route/link. Instead, it makes the text not show up. How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

**handlebar.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('hashtag', function(posttext) {
    posttext.html();
    posttext = posttext.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://www.google.com/?q=$1' target='_blank'>$&</a>");
    posttext.html(posttext);
});
```

**postidem.js**

```
<h3 class="text">{{hashtag title}}</h3>
<p class="text">{{hashtag posttext}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('hashtag', function(posttext) {
    // DEBUG START : just to know that `posttext` is really what you want; remove later;
    console.log("hashtag",posttext);
    // DEBUG END

    return posttext.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a href='https://www.google.com/?q=$1' target='_blank'>$&</a>");

});
```

Note:

- `Template.registerHelper` works for Meteor 0.9.1 and newer
- `Handlebars.registerHelper` works for every version.
- Don't define global helpers in `Meteor.startup` as Blaze won't be able to find those helpers.

Remember to put helper in tripple curly braces as it returns html;

```
<h3 class="text">{{{hashtag title}}}</h3>
<p class="text">{{{hashtag posttext}}}</p>
```

**[Proof](http://meteorpad.com/pad/agu5iWaAdxEXwCcxB)**

Comment: Maybe use the more up-to-date `Template.registerHelper` ?